# Type 2 hypervisor that exposes the GPU

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, kvm-virtualization, gpu

Are there any free or paid Type 2 hypervisors for Ubuntu 22.04 that expose the GPU, preferably a Nvidia GPU?

These may require special GPU drivers for the Linux kernel, provided the special driver either is a co-process to a "standard" driver or provides Ubuntu with the same/similar functionality as the standard driver, including allowing Xwindows plus whatever GUI environment one wants (KDE, Gnome, MATE, etc).

I have read [Linux KVM Guest with GPU Passthrough doesn't work (Black Screen)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1206525/linux-kvm-guest-with-gpu-passthrough-doesnt-work-black-screen).

Will Ubuntu KVM accept existing VirtualBox/VMWare virtual machines (effectively, sets of files under Ubuntu) or can these be ported to Ubuntu KVM, and does Ubuntu KVM expose a Nvidia GPU?